# Qt Script Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, concurrency, qtscript

I need to run multiple (up to 50 or more) Qt Script Functions concurrently. Running two or three Threads with Script Functions works just fine, but as soon as I run around 50 Threads, I get an Error and my Program crashes.

```
ASSERTION FAILED: globalData().dynamicGlobalObject (..\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\runtime/JSGlobalObject.h:411 QTJSC::JSGlobalObject* QTJSC::ExecState::dynamicGlobalObject())
```

My main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QScriptEngine>
#include <threadworker.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QScriptEngine engine;
    QScriptValue val = engine.evaluate("(function() {var r = Math.random(); while(1>0) print(r);})");
    ThreadWorker *worker[50];
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++) {
        worker[i] = new ThreadWorker(val);
        QObject::connect(worker[i], SIGNAL(needsStarting()), worker[i], SLOT(startScript()));
        emit worker[i]->needsStarting();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

This is my threadworker.h:

```
#ifndef THREADWORKER_H
#define THREADWORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QScriptValue>
#include <QThread>

class ThreadWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ThreadWorker(QObject *parent = 0);

    explicit ThreadWorker(QScriptValue function);

signals:
    needsStarting();
public slots:
    void startScript();
private:
    QScriptValue value;
    QThread thread;
};

#endif // THREADWORKER_H
```

This is my threadworker.cpp:

```
#include "threadworker.h"
#include <QDebug>

ThreadWorker::ThreadWorker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

ThreadWorker::ThreadWorker(QScriptValue function)
{
    value = function;
    this->moveToThread(&thread);
    thread.start();
}

void ThreadWorker::startScript()
{
    value.call();
}
```

I expected, that independently of the amount, the Qt Script Threads would run just fine and I can't understand what is causing this contrary behaviour.

Comment: did you try to create threads in main() and moving those object into those threads in main() too?

Comment: @ni1ight just tried it. Doesn't change anything. Still the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the `QScriptEngine` on worker class and let `moveToThread` move it to the the worker thread, seems to solve:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void startScript(const QString &function);

private:
    QScriptEngine engine;
    QScriptValue value;
};
```

However, it will be a challenge create so many threads and release them properly on application exit. I suggest you to use pooled threads, for example, `QtConcurrent`. `QtConcurrent` allows you (for example but not limited to) multithread with just functions, not necessarly classes, and with [`QFutureSyncronyzer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturesynchronizer.html) you can in one call wait for all the threads you want to finish. See [`QtConcurrent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html):

```
#include <QtScript>
#include <QtConcurrent>

#define THREADS 50

void worker_function(const QString &function)
{
    QScriptEngine engine;
    QScriptValue value;

    value = engine.evaluate(function);
    value.call();
}

...
QFutureSynchronizer<void> synchronizer;

//Set the max pooled threads
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(THREADS);

//Start all threads and add them to the future synchronizer
for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
    synchronizer.addFuture(QtConcurrent::run(worker_function, QString("(function() {var r = Math.random(); while(1>0) print(r);})")));

//Wait for all threads to finish
synchronizer.waitForFinished();
...
```

Comment: So basically, with both solutions, you create as many ScriptEngines, as you make function calls?

Comment: Yes, but if i'm correct it will share `globalObject`. However it's a guess, considering i'm novice in Qt Script. ;)